# Data in database is entered only for the first time

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Iam trying to create a private messaging system in which user sends message to another user and that content is inserted into database..Iam using a random number called hash to identify a conversation between two people..table for that is "message_group" and table for saving messages is "messages"..here comes the problem..
When I type something in text area and click on sendmessage button it inserts the data into the messages database..But if type something again and try to send it , the data wont enter into database..coz of this the other person is getting only first message..Please help me solving this problem..here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>new convo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php';?>
<?php include 'message_title_bar.php';?>
<?php include 'functions.php';?>

<div>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){ 
?>


<form method='post'>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){


        $my_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $user=$_GET['user'];
    $random_number=rand();
    $message=$_POST['message'];


    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $query_string = "SELECT `hash` FROM `message_group` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id' AND `user_two`='$user') OR (`user_one`='$user' AND `user_two`='$my_id')";

  $check_con=mysqli_query($connect,$query_string) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_con)==1){
        echo "<p>Conversation already Started</p>";
    }else{
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO message_group VALUES('$my_id' , '$user' , '$random_number')");
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('','$random_number','$my_id','$message')");
    echo "<p>Conversation started</p>";
    }
}
?>

Enter message:<br />
<textarea name='message' rows='7' cols='60'></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<input type='submit' name="submit" value="sendmessage" />
</form>


<?php


}

else{
    echo "<b>Select User</b>";
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');
   $user_list=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users`");
    while($run_user=mysqli_fetch_array($user_list)){
       $user = $run_user['id'];
        $username = $run_user['username'];
        echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>";
        }
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use ajax for chat system or comment system... And avoid connecting database so many times...

Comment: Try using insert function this way `mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO `tablename`(`id`,`msg`) VALUES ('$id','$msg')");`

Comment: I just know little php and mysqli..I never learned ajax and jquery..so I didnt use it :( ..anyway Thanks for ur suggestion brother@DeepakKumar

Comment: I tried what u told me but didnt work..Can u suggest me some other methods? @DeepakKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html><head><title>new convo</title></head><body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php include 'message_title_bar.php'; ?>
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
<?php $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_mysql_login_system'); if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); ?>
<div>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])) {
    ?>
    <form method='post'>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
            $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $user = $_GET['user'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $query_string = "SELECT `hash` FROM `message_group` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id' AND `user_two`='$user') OR (`user_one`='$user' AND `user_two`='$my_id')";
            $check_con = mysqli_query($connect, $query_string);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($check_con)) {
                $f_array = mysqli_fetch_array($check_con);
                $hash = $f_array['hash'];
                echo "<p>Conversation already Started</p>";
            } else {
                $hash = rand();
                mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO message_group VALUES('$my_id' , '$user' , '$hash')");
                echo "<p>Conversation started</p>";
            }
            mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('', '$hash', '$my_id', '$message')");
        }
        ?>
        <label for="message">Enter message:</label>
        <textarea name='message' id="message" rows='7' cols='60'></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' name="submit" value="sendmessage"/>
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    echo "<b>Select User</b>";
    $user_list = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users`");
    while ($run_user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_list)) {
        $user = $run_user['id'];
        $username = $run_user['username'];
        echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>";
    }
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need out this line from your "if (mysqli_num_rows($check_con)) {" mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('','$random_number','$my_id','$message')");

Comment: Thank you so much for your time brother! but I couldnt follow what u did there..can u be more specific in the parts which u have modified?thanks again @Oversun

Comment: You need close your "if" in this line "if(mysqli_num_rows($check_con)==1){" before insert new message into your db. And after this line mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO message_group VALUES('$my_id' , '$user' , '$random_number')");
                echo "<p>Conversation started</p>";

Comment: when I did what u told me..The message_group table works fine (meaning~only one hash(random value) created for that convo) but in messages table there are two different hash values..one is same as in message_group table so it is displayed..but other is different hash so those hash messages which starts from second message are not displayed @Oversun

Comment: u know what?It just worked..Thanks a ton! and another simple qstn..In the Select User list it displays all the list of users including me..I dont want my name to be displayed there coz i dont want to msg myself..how not to display my name?@oversun

Comment: np :) For your question just change your qry with $user_list = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users` WHERE `id` != 'YOUR ID NUMBER HERE!' ");

Comment: Undefined variable: my_id in D:\wamp\www\2\send.php on line 41..this is the error..line is $user_list = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `id`,`username` FROM `users` WHERE id != '$my_id' ");@Oversun

Comment: U haven't $my_id value in this place. U need add this row <?php $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; ?> before connection line <?php $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost'.... etc

Comment: Who are you sir? Everything works for the first time itself..Thanks you a lot! Today is my lucky day..@Oversun

Comment: Please answer this qstn..My life would be complete if u answer that! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093413/data-entered-in-text-area-wont-enter-into-database] @Oversun

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in code brother read basic first... and you are not  using echo function to print old chat.

Just echo old chat. before post function.

```
steps:
1. Check if users already chatting.
2. If they are chatting echo chat which they already chatted.
3. If not chatting then start new chat.
4. if they are not chatting you dont need to echo anything just echo new message.
```

Your present code will just show you last message i think. because your page getting reload. and after it loads its just printing your last message in my view.. you need to print old chat as well.