# data entered in text area wont enter into database designed using php and mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a private messaging system in which user sends message to another user and that content is inserted into database..Iam using a random number called hash to identify a conversation between two people..table for that is "message_group" and table for saving messages is "messages"..here comes the problem..when I type something in text area it is supposed to enter into database table messages but it doesnot..This code is supposed to display the messages and also reply to a message by typing in textarea..someone please help me..This is the final error in my project..I will get A grade if this succeeds..Thanks
here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>convo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'connect.php';?>
    <?php include 'message_title_bar.php';?>
    <?php include 'functions.php';?>
    <?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>
    <?php
  $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 ?>
    <br />
    <div>
        <?php
   if(isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
     $hash=$_GET['hash'];

     $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
     $message_query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT from_id,message FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$hash'") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
     while($run_message=mysqli_fetch_array($message_query)){
         $from_id=$run_message['from_id'];
         $message=$run_message['message'];
         $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
           $user_query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$from_id'") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
            $run_user=mysqli_fetch_array($user_query);
                 $from_username=$run_user['username'];
                 echo "
        <p>
            <b>$from_username</b>
            <br />$message
        </p>";  


     }
    ?>
        <form method='post'>
            <?php

if(isset($POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){

$new_message=$_POST['message'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','$hash','my_id','new_message')");
    header('location:conversations.php?hash='.$hash);
}
?>

Enter message:
            <br />
            <textarea name='message' rows='7' cols='60'></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type='submit' value="send message" />
        </form>
        <?php


}else {
            echo"
        <b>select conversation</b>";
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system') or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $query_string="SELECT `hash`,`user_one`,`user_two` FROM message_group WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'";
    $get_con=mysqli_query($connect,$query_string) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        while($run_con = mysqli_fetch_array($get_con))
    {   $hash=$run_con['hash'];
        $user_one=$run_con['user_one'];
        $user_two=$run_con['user_two'];

if($user_one==$my_id){
    $select_id = $user_two;
}else{
    $select_id = $user_one;
}
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$select_id'";
        $user_get=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        $run_user=mysqli_fetch_array($user_get);
        $select_username = $run_user['username'];


       echo "
        <p>
            <a href='conversations.php?hash=$hash'>$select_username</a>
        </p>";      

    }

}
?>
    </div>
</body>
```

I strongly somehow feel that the error is in this part of the above code
Note: **Below code is a section of above code**

```
?>
    <br />
    <form method='post'>
    <?php
    if(isset($POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
    $new_message=$_POST['message'];
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','$hash','my_id','new_message')");
    header('location:conversations.php?hash='.$hash);}
    ?>Enter message: <br />
<textarea name='message' rows='6' cols='50'></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type='submit' value="send message" />
    </form>
<?php
```

Comment: Try this:- `mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','$hash','$my_id','$new_message')");`

Comment: you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','$hash','my_id','new_message')");` do the same as you did for the others where you're using `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: yeah I jus noticed and did that!but still the same brother..thanks anyway @Fred-ii-

Comment: well.... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I also don't know why you're using `$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','php_mysql_login_system');` thrice.

Comment: using it thrice wont create any errors anyway no?@Fred-ii-

Comment: You should really go and read some beginner tutorials on how to handle database stuff in PHP, as well as on some _basic_ debugging strategies.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the problem in the code?And Iam a absolute beginner..I ll learn eventually ..thanks@CBroe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head><title>convo</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php include 'message_title_bar.php'; ?>
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
<?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>
<?php
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_mysql_login_system');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
if (isset($POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && isset($_SESSION['hash']) && !empty($_SESSION['hash'])) {
    $hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
    $new_message = $_POST['message'];
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO messages VALUES('', '$hash', '$my_id', '$new_message')");
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/conversations.php?hash=".$hash);
    exit;
}
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
    $_SESSION['hash'] = $_GET['hash'];
    $hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
    $message_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT from_id, message FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$hash'");
    while ($run_message = mysqli_fetch_array($message_query)) {
        $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
        $message = $run_message['message'];
        $run_user = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$from_id'"));
        $from_username = $run_user['username'];
        echo "<p><b>$from_username</b><br />$message</p>";
    }
    ?>
    <form method='post'>
        <label for="message">Enter message:</label>
        <textarea name='message' id="message" rows='7' cols='60'></textarea>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' value="send message"/>
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    echo "<b>select conversation</b>";
    $query_string = "SELECT `hash`, `user_one`, `user_two` FROM message_group WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'";
    $get_con = mysqli_query($connect, $query_string);
    while ($run_con = mysqli_fetch_array($get_con)) {
        $hash = $run_con['hash'];
        $user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
        $user_two = $run_con['user_two'];

        if ($user_one == $my_id) {
            $select_id = $user_two;
        } else {
            $select_id = $user_one;
        }
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$select_id'";
        $run_user = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect, $query));
        $select_username = $run_user['username'];
        echo "<p><a href='?hash=".$hash."'>$select_username</a></p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: heyy thanks for ur time..But I got 2 errors 1) ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: user_id in D:\wamp\www\2\conversations.php on line 10  and 2)( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: hash in D:\wamp\www\2\conversations.php on line 13 @Oversun

Comment: yes..session_start(); is in functions.php ..This is conversations.php ...Jus one error now( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: hash in D:\wamp\www\2\conversations.php on line 13@Oversun

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: hash in D:\wamp\www\2\conversations.php on line 14..Still the same sir :( @Oversun

Comment: can we use this to suppress that notice? <?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>@Oversun

Comment: no sir..but I have an idea..In the previous qstn u solved about send.php it inserts messages into message table..if a user sends msg for first time it says convo started..and for 2nd time it says convo alrdy started..but it doesnt display the convo..so my idea is why dont we use the conecpt of displaying convo from this conversations.php and implement in send.php?@Oversun

Comment: It erased the notice but it displays conversation of some other users rather than the list of conversations..and submitting data in text area also not entering into database @Oversun

Comment: it says ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: user_id in D:\wamp\www\2\conversations.php on line 10 for above code and the users list is not displayed@Oversun